# Is there a way to share reactive data between random components in Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Having some reactive const in "Component A," which may update after some user action, how could this data be imported into another component?
For example:

```
const MyComponent = {
      import { computed, ref } from "vue";
      setup() {
        name: "Component A",
        setup() {
          const foo = ref(null);
          
          const updateFoo = computed(() => foo.value = "bar");
          
          return { foo }
        }
      }
    }
```

Could the updated value of 'foo' be used in another Component without using provide/inject?

I am pretty new in the Vue ecosystem; kind apologies if this is something obvious that I am missing here.

Comment: Is your "random" component going to be used in Component A,or is it going to be located outside of it?

Comment: @terry it will be located outside of it. I could have use props, I know but I need to share data between two independent components

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the best things about `composition API` is that we can create reusable logic and use that all across the App. You create a `composable functions` in which you can create the logic and then import that into the components where you want to use it. Not only does this make your component much cleaner but also your APP much more maintainable. Below is a simple example of counter to show how they can be used. You can find working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-composition-api-blfpj) here:

Create a composable function for counter:

```
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
const counter = ref(0);
export const getCounter = () => {
  const incrementCounter = () => counter.value++;
  const decrementCounter = () => counter.value--;
  const counterPositiveOrNegitive = computed(() =>
    counter.value >= 0 ? " Positive" : "Negitive"
  );
  return {
    counter,
    incrementCounter,
    decrementCounter,
    counterPositiveOrNegitive
  };
};
```

Then you can import this function into your components and get the function or you want to use. Component to increment counter.

```
 <template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Component To Increment Counter</h1>
    <button @click="incrementCounter">Increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getCounter } from "../composables/counterExample";
export default {
  name: "IncrementCounter",
  setup() {
    const { incrementCounter } = getCounter();
    return { incrementCounter };
  },
};
</script>
```

Component to decrement counter:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Component To Decrement Counter</h1>
    <button @click="decrementCounter">Decrement</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getCounter } from "../composables/counterExample";
export default {
  name: "DecrementCounter",
  setup() {
    const { decrementCounter } = getCounter();
    return { decrementCounter };
  },
};
</script>
```

Then in the main component, you can show the counter value.

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <div class="counters">
    <IncrementCounter />
    <DecrementCounter />
  </div>
  <h3>Main Component </h3>
  <p>Counter: {{ counter }}</p>
  <p>{{ counterPositiveOrNegitive }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import IncrementCounter from "./components/IncrementCounter.vue";
import DecrementCounter from "./components/DecrementCounter.vue";
import { getCounter } from "./composables/counterExample";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    IncrementCounter: IncrementCounter,
    DecrementCounter: DecrementCounter,
  },
  setup() {
    const { counter, counterPositiveOrNegitive } = getCounter();
    return { counter, counterPositiveOrNegitive };
  },
};
```

Hope this was somewhat helpful. You can find a working example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-composition-api-blfpj

Comment: Very interesting @Humayon, indeed and really clean approach.
However I was thinking of a case where the functionality and the logic must be tied up to each component. For example, having a component with a user input with some validation logic stored in a const and another Component having access to this validation const. I don't know if this data can be shared across components.

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can do this. One approach would be you can communicate data between components using props/emits. Here is a code pen for communication data between components:
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-buck-kith5?file=/src/App.vue

Further, you can view the vue documentation: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html

Comment: You can also use a veux store as the single source of truth for your app which holds all the data which can be accessed anywhere. You can read about it here:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store